# EntityFramework Include

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

This is my domain use for Entity Framework

```
public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
public int DefaultCurrency { get; set; }
public virtual Currency FunCurrency { get; set; }
public int DefaultFunCurrency { get; set; }
```

by default if put `.Include(c => c.Currency);`
it will bind to `CurrencyId`, 
but in my case i need to link the property to `DefaultCurrenncy`

Help

Comment: Are you asking how to make `DefaultCurrency` the foreign key for the `Currency` relationship?

Comment: can you provide more context (more relevant code).  These bits of code don't make sense on their own.

Comment: What's your configuration code? Sounds like your issue is multiple instances of the same entity in a model. If that's the case, you can use the InverseProperty attribute or fluent config to assign currency to the desired FK: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships